# How do I get the index of string variable value into ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

In my windows phone application I am using observablecollection like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class createGroups : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string buttonName = "";
        public static ObservableCollection<Group> groupbtn;

        public createGroups()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            groupbtn = new ObservableCollection<Group>();        
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string buttonText = "abc"
            string index = groupbtn.IndexOf(buttonText);                      
        }

    }
}
```

And below is the `Group` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public class Group
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        /*public string content { get; set; }
        private string[] numberofbtns = new string[5];
        public string[] NumberOfBtns
        {
            get { return numberofbtns; }
            set { numberofbtns = value; }
        }*/
        //object[] array1 = new object[5];


        public Group()
        { 

        }
        public Group(Button btn)
        {
            Name = btn.Name;

        }
    }
}
```

But its getting me two errors below:

Error 1: at this line `groupbtn.IndexOf(buttonText)`:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<GetContacts.Group>.IndexOf(GetContacts.Group)' has some invalid arguments
```

Error 2 at this line `groupbtn.IndexOf(buttonText)` on it `buttonText`:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'GetContacts.Group'
```

How do I resolve it or kindly suggest me how do I get the index of string variable value into observablecollection.
Waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: `IndexOf` for any `object list` will expect same `object` to find index. In your case you need to pass `GetContacts.Group` object and not `string`. Since you are passing `string`(which is also an `object`), it is trying to convert it to `GetContacts.Group`, thus it gives you 2nd error.

Comment: Looking at the code you shared, I'm thinking that there may be another issue - about how to do things in general. Do you know about MVVM or Data Binding? If not - read about these. Normally, the UI (Buttons in your case) is created based on some (view-)model objects (Groups in your case). You seem to be doing it the other way around. A group getting its name from a Button - that's not normal.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `IndexOf` with a string on an `ObservableCollection<Group>`. You need a `Group`. You also have to override `Equals` in class `Group` (also override `GetHashCode`):

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Group g2 = obj as Group;
        return g2 != null && g2.Name == this.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name == null 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you're able to use `IndexOf`:

```
Group searchGroup = new Group { Name = buttonText };
int index = groupbtn.IndexOf(searchGroup);
```

or use a different approach, for example using LINQ:

```
int index = groupbtn
    .Select((g, i) => new { Group = g, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Group.Name == buttonText)
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the same error.  The problem is that you have a collection of type `Group` and then you are trying to find a matching `Group` with a `string`.  You have to pass a `Group` to `.IndexOf` to find the index of the `Group` you are trying to find.

This type of error is something you need to be able to figure out yourself from the compiler error.

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<GetContacts.Group>.IndexOf(GetContacts.Group)' has some invalid arguments
```

This clearly means it doesn't like the argument you are passing to this function.  It shows the function definition, so you can tell it wants to be passed a `Group`.

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'GetContacts.Group'
```

You are passing a `string` to a function that we know accepts a `Group`.  Since it only accepts a `Group`, it tries to implicitly convert the `string` to a `Group`, but there isn't a way for it automatically do that.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexOf method is expecting a Group object, but you're providing a string. ObservableCollections implement IEnumerable, so you may be able to use a Linq expression. Such as...

```
Group btnGroup = (from g in groupbtn where g.Name == "name" select g).First();
int indexOfGroupButton = groupbtn.IndexOf(btnGroup);
```

Or something like that. Basically, you first need to find the actual "Group" object, and then you can find the index of that object.

Comment: why you are using `First()` because its not necessary the string value is on the first position in the `obervablecollection`.

Comment: The ObservableCollection is not a collection of string values. It's a collection of "Group" objects. I think that's where the confusion is.

In Linq, (from g in groupbtn where g.Name == "name" select g) will return an IEnumerable<Group> (basically, a list of group objects). You want the first object in that list. Ideally, there would only be one in there, but you still need to explicitly say you want the first one.